# Почему программа работает некорректно? Как работать с массивами в Си?

Tags: c, массивы

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main()
{
     int digit_seen[10] = { 0 };
     int digit, n, i;
     setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
     printf("Введите число: ");
     scanf("d", &n);
     printf("\n");
     while (n > 0)
     {
         digit = n % 10;
         digit_seen[digit]++;
         n /= 10;
     }
     for (i = 0 ; i < 10; i++)
     {
          printf("digit_seen[%d] = %d\n", i, digit_seen[i]);
     }
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: [Как правильно задавать вопросы](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/732/176217).

Comment: Чего конкретного вы пытаетесь добиться в программе?

Comment: Простейшая программа для подсчета количества разных цифр в числе. Первый опыт использования массивов. Помогите понять в чем ошибка.

Comment: @Леонид обратите внимание на то, как я переделал оформление вашего исходника

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Ошибка тут:**

```
scanf("d", &n);
```

**Исправление:**

```
scanf("%d", &n);
```

**Объяснение:**

Формат ввода целых чисел при помощи scanf - `%d`

**Исправление явных недостатков:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main()
{       
     const size_t base = 10;

     setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");

     printf("Введите число: ");
     int n;  
     scanf("%d", &n);
     printf("\n");

     int digit_seen[base] = { 0 };
     while (n > 0)
     {
         const size_t digit = n % base;
         ++digit_seen[digit];
         n /= base;
     }
     for (size_t i = 0 ; i < base; ++i)
     {
          printf("digit_seen[%d] = %d\n", i, digit_seen[i]);
     }
     return 0;
}
```